# If lexer can pass the bad token to the parser?

Tags: parsing, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, lexical

During the lexical analysis phase of compiler if a bad token is encountered then the lexer will go into the error recovery mode and, suppose say, it discards the token until the next semicolon is seen and starts its analysis again. Then overall tokens generated  is passed to the parser ?.

What I mean to say if lexer has encountered an error then does the compilation stops at this point or it continues and goes to the parsing phase ?

Comment: It depends on the parser/lexer you use and on the configuration. Is there a concrete parser/lexer combination you want to know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During the lexical analysis phase of compiler if a bad token is encountered then the lexer will go into the error recovery mode and, suppose say, it discards the token until the next semicolon is seen and starts its analysis again.

That's only one way of doing it, and not the best.

> Then overall tokens generated is passed to the parser?

No, only the next legal token.

> What I mean to say if lexer has encountered an error then does the compilation stops at this point or it continues and goes to the parsing phase?

It continues.

But for several decades I've been practising the opposite. Instead of having the lexer try to do its own error recovery I just return the offending character to the parser. As the parser is usually equipped with much better error recovery, this leads to a much more fault-tolerant parse.

Sample *lex/flex* implementation:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

Comment: how does other languages do it. Also can you tell me if the errors that we see during the compilation are they error mixtures of the error detected in each phase of compilation or just error from one phase of compilation ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with languages. It is a property of a lexer/parser pair. I don't understand your new question either.

Comment: Okay I got from your answer above what i was trying to ask. Ignore my new question. your answer has cleared my doubt. Thanks a lot

Comment: Okay one more thing what are other ways of error recovery mode since you said that it is not the best. Please give me some link if you have where i can see different error recovery mode in parser.

Comment: I've given you my answer. Let the parser do it. If you want a different answer you'll have to get it from someone else. This is mine.

Comment: @EJP ive been looking at your answer, and wondering when you mentioned returning the character, do you mean that you are returning a single character to the parser as a token?